# Program installed to `/home/username/bin` and added to path... not launching

Tags: bash, software-installation, path

I just installed newer versions of `grep` and `vim` to my local `~/bin` directory.

I have the path added via `PATH=$PATH:$HOME/bin` in my `.bash_profile`.

When I try to run either, the version installed in `/usr/local/bin` launches. How do I override this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The way you have set your new path then /bin /usr/bin is searched before $HOME/bin
If you set it the other way around your $HOME/bin is searched first.

```
PATH=$HOME/bin:$PATH
```